# Are there areas of London the police are afraid to enter?

Tags: united-kingdom, police, london

From [*The Daily Mail (online)*](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-3352406/Scotland-Yard-mocks-Trump-s-claims-London-police-terrified-Muslim-areas-officers-claim-tycoon-RIGHT.html):

> The US presidential contender caused worldwide consternation yesterday after a string of incendiary remarks about Muslims, including in Britain, and said: 'We have places in London and other places that are so radicalised that police are afraid for their own lives.'

Which areas in London exactly are *no-go areas* for the police?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37912/discussion-on-question-by-user6836-are-there-areas-of-london-the-police-are-afra).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Skeptics.SE

Answer (score 14):

This claim is patently false.

> As is often the case, Emersons and Fox’s corrections did not travel as far or fast to those who saw and believed the claims made during the Fox News segment, and his retraction did not address the claims he had made earlier about no-go zones in France. While large populations of Muslim residents inhabit cities and towns affected by the rumor (and may adhere to religious custom in large numbers), no areas of England, France, or the United States currently allow the laws of any religion to override their own laws.

[Source : Snopes](http://www.snopes.com/politics/religion/nogozones.asp)

> This message is spreading rapidly through the toxic echo chamber of US news organisations, being amplified as it goes by the tendency of the internet to feed off itself. It is a message that hitherto has mostly been taken up only by the disreputable right in Europe – organisations such as Britain First and the EDL.

[Source : Politics.co.uk](http://www.politics.co.uk/comment-analysis/2015/01/15/comment-the-myth-of-muslim-no-go-areas-is-being-used-to-turn)

> There are no no-go areas in England.

[Source : Quora.com](https://www.quora.com/Can-anyone-name-any-of-the-alleged-no-go-areas-in-England)

> A British Redditor bought a bottle of wine and went for a nighttime walk around Woolwich in response to another user who insisted he'd get attacked in one of London's "radicalised" no-go zones.

[Source - The Independent](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/home-news/trump-london-no-go-zones-radicalised-woolwich-reddit-video-a6766511.html)

> Donald Trump Supporter Claims There Are ‘No Go Areas’ In England And Gets Promptly Schooled By Brits

[Source - Huffington Post](http://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/entry/donald-trump-supporter-no-go-areas_uk_5934289ae4b0c242ca250a0e)

Interestingly, in my (brief) search for sources about this [proving that no-go areas don't exist], exactly the opposite line came from:

- The Daily Mail ([Guardian article](https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2017/feb/08/wikipedia-bans-daily-mail-as-unreliable-source-for-website))
- The Daily Express
- The Sun
- Breitbart

All of which are generally known as unreliable sources.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker - curious to understand why you edited out the "right wing nonsense" bit. The info stemmed from Fox news and the Daily Mail, which hardly qualify as a left wing news outlet.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy  It's name-calling, and doesn't help the reader better understand the answer.  I've rolled it back to Carpetsmoker's revision

Answer (score 8):

[In December 2015](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2015/dec/08/the-met-blasts-donald-trump-for-london-police-in-fear-muslims-claim) the [British Government](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-london-35037007), the Mayor of London, and the Metropolitan [London] Police all rejected the claim.  Downing Street said the claims were "totally inaccurate", the then Mayor of London Boris Johnson said they were "utter nonsense", and the Met said:

> "We would not normally dignify such comments with a response, however,
>   on this occasion we think it’s important to state to Londoners that Mr
>   Trump could not be more wrong... Any candidate for the presidential
>   election in the United States of America is welcome to receive a
>   briefing from the Met police on the reality of policing London."

The Prime Minister's spokesperson said:

> "The Prime Minister completely disagrees with the comments made by
>   Donald Trump, which are divisive, unhelpful and quite simply wrong,"

Boris Johnson went on to say:

> "As a city where more than 300 languages are spoken, London has a
>   proud history of tolerance and diversity and to suggest there are
>   areas where police officers cannot go because of radicalisation is
>   simply ridiculous... Crime has been falling steadily both in London
>   and in New York - the only reason I wouldn't go to some parts of New
>   York is the real risk of meeting Donald Trump"

Also worth noting that at the time the government, prime minister, and mayor of London were all Conservative.  So their reaction can hardly be dismissed as leftist conspiracy or such.

If there's any parts of the country where the police can't go owing to radicalisation, it's likely only some parts of Northern Ireland. See [The Troubles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Troubles).

Answer (score 1):

Trump made the negative remarks about Britain and the Muslims living in Britain because he was angered about a petition to the British parliament which was set up after his remarks to ban Muslims entering US.
This [petition](https://petition.parliament.uk/petitions/114003) demands to ban Trump from entering the UK because of hate speech and reached nearly 550.000 signatures in a few days.

> The UK has banned entry to many individuals for hate speech. The same
>   principles should apply to everyone who wishes to enter the UK.
>
> If the United Kingdom is to continue applying the 'unacceptable
>   behaviour' criteria to those who wish to enter its borders, it must be
>   fairly applied to the rich as well as poor, and the weak as well as
>   powerful.

After the petition was set up and reached more and more supporters by the hour, Trump came out with his remarks about Britain having a problem with Muslims.

Trumps claim is not true. There are no areas in London, the police is afraid to enter.

> I very much doubt the person quoted by the Daily Mail was a Lancashire
>   police officer, because it’s just not true. ([source](http://www.lep.co.uk/news/local/claims-of-muslim-no-go-areas-in-preston-absolute-tosh-say-police-1-7618630))

Even the columnist of the Daily Mail, who claimed these no-go areas for non-Muslims would exist and who was praised by Trump for her statement, [cannot name these areas](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/people/katie-hopkins-no-go-areas-non-muslims-in-andrew-neil-bbc-daily-politics-interview-legally-accurate-a6769516.html).

The Daily Mail is one of Britain's newspapers being responsible for the increase of Islamophobia in Britain, [following the ideology of demonisation of Muslims](http://www.ihrc.org.uk/publications/reports/5679-the-british-media-and-muslim-representation-the-ideology-of-demonisation-).

Comment: Link to petition: https://petition.parliament.uk/petitions/114003

Comment: You are providing background information but unfortunately you aren't answering the question, which is "Are there areas of London the police are afraid to enter?". The motives of Donald Trump for making this statement is not part of the question, only its truthfulness.

Comment: @Noor Thank you for editing the answer to be more on-topic. But unfortunately your first article is about the city of Preston, not about London, the second article is just about a television columnist being badly prepared in an interview and the third article does not address this particular topic at all.

Comment: It should also be pointed out that the "journalist" for the Mail, wasn't a typical journalist but was hired to write opinion pieces based on her controversial take on many issues, and she was also fired from the Mail for instigating one too many lawsuits. She also filed for bankruptcy after libelling Jack Monroe and refusing to apologise.

Answer (score -3):

Actually the U.K. Daily Mail has a number of stories up about no-go zones in the U.K. and areas where police must refrain from wearing uniforms to protect their identity. One story that quotes some active duty law enforcement officers in the U.K. and specifically in London that seem to corroborate what Trump said.  Here are just two I found in minutes. [here](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2541635/Murders-rapes-going-unreported-no-zones-police-minority-communities-launch-justice-systems.html) and [here](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-3352406/Scotland-Yard-mocks-Trump-s-claims-London-police-terrified-Muslim-areas-officers-claim-tycoon-RIGHT.html).

It's amazing to me that so many people are willing to vehemently defend a position that is so easily refuted by just a minimum amount of fact checking.

Comment: The last line seems unnecessarily antagonistic, but the articles are very good for explaining Trump's statement. +1

Comment: You will not find 'facts' in the Daily Mail. It is a newspaper written for people in Britain with the sort of mentality of those who Trump hopes to recruit in America. However I did note that even Nigel Farage,(leader of the United Kingdom Independence Party (UKIP) - a right wing anti-immigrant, anti Britain's membership of the EU, party) declared that even he thought Trump was talking tripe. (or words to that effect).

Comment: This is from the article itself "It’s not that the police are afraid to go into these areas or don’t want to go into those areas,’ he said. ‘But if the police don’t get calls for help then, of course, they won’t know what’s going on.’" This is very different from what Trump said. People need to read the whole article and not just the click bate titles.

Comment: @DammandCherry This is quintessential *Daily Mail* stuff. The headlines and the opening paragraphs are sensational. But the truth is often contained further down the page, or inside. It is the news as a certain section of the public would prefer to understand it. Just to retain our sanity, this is from todays [*Guardian*](http://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2015/dec/10/donald-trump-responds-uk-petition-criticism-muslims). The *Mail* columnist, Katie Hopkins, who appeared on Fox News in support of Trump, was the person who compared the migrants fleeing across the Mediterranean to cockroaches.

Comment: I totally agree with WS2 in his comments about the Daily Mail. This paper should not be used as to proof the truthfulness of a statement.

Comment: There have been no-go areas at many times in the past, that have nothing to do with the paranoia about _randomgroup_ under your bed.

Comment: You should add better sources to substantiate this claim. The Daily Mail is just yellow press, not reliable in the least. So please, do some fact-checking indeed.

Answer (score -3):

In my experience there aren't any 'no go' areas in this country. The closest may be a few Catholic neighbourhoods in Belfast where the PSNI are not exactly looked at with affection shall we say. But even they neighbourhoods - police will enter.

Comment: And you have been traveling to all the suburbs and corners of the UK? Personal opinion isn't necessarily a relevant basis.

Comment: This would be a much better answer if you could provide links to substantive information. As noted by @bilbo_pingouin, opinion isn't a great source for answers.